# How is it possible that some extra-dimensional pouches can store living things while others can't?

Tags: magic, spacetime-dimensions, logistics, dimensions

The extra-dimensional pouch is a portable and lightweight container that is capable of storing almost unlimited tangible objects of any sizes inside a pocket dimension, but why might certain extra dimensional pouches be able to store living things such as livestock, for example chickens, cattle, fish out of water, etc, but there are some which are not suitable for life?

Comment: Is this asking what in your world causes some "bags of holding" to support life, and others which cannot support life? Or is this asking why some "bags of holding" can *contain* living things and other simply can not *contain* them? Please clarify the problem in the description. Can a living thing physically get into both bags or not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions are required to be specific and answerable, and are expected to not permit every answer to be equally valuable. You haven't provided any limitations, conditions or expectations about answers, so I doubt you can explain how you'll pick a best answer - and without that ability, this is just brainstorming, which the [help/on-topic] states isn't a good fit for this Stack.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why can you carry an alive kitten in a cardboard box with some holes in it, while you cannot do the same if the box is filled with water?

Simply said, because the internal conditions of the box in one case can support the living functions of the kitten, in the other case not.

Same goes for your xd-pouches: if the internal conditions are such that they can sustain life, the living things will keep be living, else not.

Comment: Of course, the reverse would be true if you were wanting to carry live *fish* in a box...

Comment: What could the internal conditions be like such that anything alive is killed instantly (some living creatures are extremely hardy) but nothing non-living you put into it will be damaged at all?

Answer (score 14):

Like pretty much everything you can think of, especially when magic is involved, there are numerous ways to skin this particular cat.

"Dimensional storage" is simply a popular label given to all kinds of containers that are able to hold things larger than their external volume, not tied to any specific effect. The mechanics of how they function varies greatly between different sources and types: conversion to/from mana structures, size (and mass) manipulation, micro portals to other planes, spacial distortion... and so on. If you can imagine it, someone has probably figured out how to create it with the right combination of magic.

Now clearly there are certain requirements for life to survive both within the container and the process that gets it in and out of the container. Life is, after all, much more than simple mechanics. Even if you provide a suitable set of conditions inside the container - a compatible atmosphere that won't go stale for instance - it's possible that certain types of containers are simply incompatible with life. For instance, containers that store their contents in a separate plane of existence might not support the existence of souls. Or perhaps the physical laws are subtly different, and without the right protective enchantments any local life that goes into the container is simply going to die on the way in.

On the other hand, spacial manipulation keeps the contents in our own space, just stretched. As long as there's a supply of oxygen, water and other requirements then living things would be fine.

Oh, and if you have one of those funny boxes where time doesn't pass on the inside, don't put your cat in it. The operator is protected from the effect by a protective enchantment, but everything else goes through a weird temporal gradient that is just flat deadly to living beings. It's great for keeping food hot though, if you can afford it.

Comment: Not least the possibility of the storage device "losing" the outer millimetre of whatever you put in it.  That'd skin anything.

Answer (score 11):

Like almost every other commodity in the world, it depends on how much you are willing to pay for the pouch.  Some wizards specialize in producing a lot of cheap pouches, where the quality is not sufficient to support life, others spend more time and effort creating pouches that will definitely support life, but the extra time results in higher prices.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is partially given in the name: "extra-**dimensional** pouch":

***What* dimension is not specified.**

Maybe their crafters can tie these pouches to specific dimensions, maybe it depends on the interdimensional configuration at the time the dimensions were tied to the pouches.
In any case, some dimensions will allow for any object thrown into it to enter a temporal stasis, and not or barely age (alternatively, pouches might be available that rapidly age everything inside).

Answer (score 7):

All extradimensional spaces are harmful to life.  Perhaps they must be filled with an inert gas, such as argon.  Living things placed in such an environment cannot reasonably survive more than a few seconds.

However, some extradimensional storage spaces are linked to our world by a portal that always links to the same time you put the object in.  That is to say, from our perspective, time only progresses in the extradimensional space when you are actively putting something in or taking something out.  From the perspective of the storage space, objects enter via portal, and are immediately removed via portal, constantly.

It doesn't matter that the extradimensional space is harmful to living things, because they're only in there for the duration of the time it takes to put it in and take it out.

Such extradimensional spaces can only store one thing at a time, which makes them extremely inconvenient if you don't absolutely need the thing to be in psuedo-suspended animation for the duration.  For anything that's not living, you want the other kind of storage, where you just dump the stuff in and retrieve whatever at your leisure, time progressing as normal.

Answer (score 6):

Each bag connects to a distinct and unique universe which has its own physical laws. Most of these universes are quite hostile to life... the mass of the neutron is double that of the proton. Or the speed of light is 3in/week. There are only strange quarks. Etc.

None of these are compatible with our biology. When a living thing is placed into one of those bags, catastrophic changes occur ending life quite quickly. Removing the living being reverts most of the base physical changes, but don't repair the damage caused.

One of those bags, quite randomly and unexpectedly, connected to a universe with either identical physical laws, or physical laws so close to our own that life isn't instantly rendered impossible. That universe permits chemistry, it doesn't cause particles to decay into forms that emit harmful radiation, and in general if the being or person isn't claustrophobic and is provided breathable air, can remain there in principle for hours, days, or weeks.

This need not be replicable. That bag in particular can be an enormous fluke that no one will imitate again. Either deliberately or by accident. It need not be indefinite... some physical laws might permit temporary habitation but longer term stays could be fatal (those that lower the rate of spontaneous decay of important subatomic particles, for instance). It's even possible that the effect would itself be impermanent as it's postulated that sometimes the fundamental constants themselves can change as a universe ages. So, whatever your narrative intentions, this theory shouldn't unduly limit those. Do what you like.

Comment: It seems to me that laws that diverse would also be problematic for non-living things.  For instance, causing particles to decay into radiation would degrade non-living objects to some degree even if the underlying changes (strange quarks back to normal or whatever) were reverted when the object is removed.

Comment: @Michael My examples were rather extreme... I tend towards hyperbole. My bad. Yes, there are undoubtedly universes where even getting back purely physical objects would be difficult, dangerous, or even impossible. And those are probably closer to the examples I provided. More subtle changes though would just mess up our precious carbon/oxygen/hydrogen chemistry, or maybe screw around with ATP or something.

Answer (score 4):

**The spatial dimensions work differently, so does time.**

When it's in the pouch (say a chicken or fish), it'll experience just a few seconds of time, but the outside world might experience days or weeks, depending on the relative ratios of the time passing.

A ratio of 604,800:1 would be a second experienced by the chicken or the  fish-out-of-water per week stored, fish are fine with that sort of thing (apart from being a little grumpy about it).

Coincidentally, the same ratio would give a 1 litre bag (two pints-ish) approximately 600 cubic metres, or a room about 40 metres (120 feet) square with a ceiling high enough for the tallest cow (even with horns), or as many ex-wives as you like.

Other pockets for different purposes have a great spatial ratio, but the time ratio is nearer normal. There are even cheap knock-offs sold by apprentices and unscrupulous hacks that have the time ratio reversed, spoiling the food faster and ageing things - useful for ageing wine, seasoning timber and faking antiques but not much for the everyday farmer.

Answer (score 2):

What have you been putting into those pouches?

If you buy one of these from a thrift store, there is a chance some angsty teenager was using it for necromancy. The sheer amount of methane, sulfide and other corpse-related gases may nlt be suitable for life.

Or maybe it belonged to some old summonner who left a beholder inside and forgot about it.

Even a pristine pouch might be inadequate. If it's too small there might not be enough air inside. If it's too big even small animals may get lost.

Preparing a pouch to function as a pokéball requires care and dedication. Pouches that hold cattle are probably checked in by a druid every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this was answered a long time ago but wanted to toss another into the hat.

The reason is in the name. "Extra dimensions" are dimensions with rules that exist outside Einstein's theories of space and time or "reality as we know it". The rules for each extra dimension do not have to be the same.

Something that is interdimensional would follow the same rules as our own reality or whatever reality is considered normal in your universe. Different interdimensions may look different, but physics will be the same as ours.

Answer (score 0):

When anything enters an extra-dimensional pouch, there are complicated magics that **disassemble** the thing so that it can be stored in this strange dimension. While stored, the things are reduced to something elementary, e.g., particles, sand, ether, mana, energy, information, or maybe something incomprehensible. When a thing is desired from the pouch, the magics will quickly locate the pieces, retrieve them all, and **reassemble** the thing exactly as it was when it entered.

While doing this all for an inanimate object is complicated, it is *much* more complicated for a living creature. Living things are always moving, have energy in them, have memories, perhaps even have souls; all of this requires much more intricate spellcrafting in order to properly take apart and put back together again.

Answer (score 0):

It is a <strike>narrative convenience</strike> magichemical mystery just how many dimensional pouches open up into dimensions that specifically mess up [amide bonds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amide). Store anything else you like and they come back fine -- metals, diamonds. Even wood doesn't do too badly. But you throw in anything with too much protein (or Kevlar, oddly), and you have to be prepared to retrieve a scrambled mess.

On the plus side, magiscrambled eggs taste *amazing*.

Answer (score 0):

Extra-dimensional containers all use the same dimension. Depending on the needs, they open onto different parts of that dimension. Some have solid walls and therefore nothing from the other dimension goes in or out, including air. Some are porous to air and open in the air. Some are porous to water, and open in fresh or salt water as required, for storing water-breathing creatures and whatnot.
This solves your problem AND makes for a hilarious encounter where your protagonists travel (accidentally perhaps) to this dimension, and just see a ridiculous number of squares and spheres all over the place just hovering on the spot. One for every container in your world.